# Pass value to textbox from another page using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages not popup. I want pass value from one to textbox in another one. And then close sender page.

If i use popup, I use this codes

My textbox in first page codes.

```
<input type="text" name="ModelTulID" id="ModelTulID"/>
```

Sender page's codes:

```
<input name="ModelID" type="hidden" value="<%=ID%>" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="sec()">              
<script type="text/javascript">
function Sec() {
    if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
        var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("ModelTulID");
        txtName.value = document.getElementById("ModelID").value;
    }
    window.close();
}
```

But my pages are not popup and i don't know what i do. I tried window.top instead window.opener but it didn't work.

Thanks for your helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you may want to take a look at is Javascript cross page cookies.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

[Set Get Cookie Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/ks1arj6h/)

```js
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  } else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```